# Nested Hash - Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have the following Nested Hash

```
def testy_user
 {
  search_templates: { 
     profile_1: { default_search_form: 'simple', name: 'Automation Profile', default_profile: 'yes', profile_set: 'standard', ref_required: 'no', fk_search_type_id: '1' },
     profile_2: { default_search_form: '', name: 'Potential Links', default_profile: 'no', profile_set: 'standard', ref_required: 'no', fk_search_type_id: '1' },
     profile_3: { default_search_form: '', name: 'Insolvency', default_profile: 'no', profile_set: 'standard', ref_required: 'no', fk_search_type_id: '1' },
     profile_4: { default_search_form: '', name: 'Mortality', default_profile: 'no', profile_set: 'standard', ref_required: 'no', fk_search_type_id: '1' },
     profile_5: { default_search_form: '', name: 'Mortality', default_profile: 'no', profile_set: 'standard', ref_required: 'no', fk_search_type_id: '1' },
     profile_6: { default_search_form: '', name: 'PRS', default_profile: 'no', profile_set: 'standard', ref_required: 'no', fk_search_type_id: '1' },
     profile_7: { default_search_form: '', name: 'Neighbour', default_profile: 'no', profile_set: 'standard', ref_required: 'no', fk_search_type_id: '1' },
     profile_8: { default_search_form: '', name: 'Smartlinks', default_profile: 'no', profile_set: 'standard', ref_required: 'no', fk_search_type_id: '1' },
     profile_9: { default_search_form: '', name: 'Property', default_profile: 'no', profile_set: 'standard', ref_required: 'no', fk_search_type_id: '1' },
     profile_10: { default_search_form: '', name: 'Occupants', default_profile: 'no', profile_set: 'standard', ref_required: 'no', fk_search_type_id: '1' }
     }
 }
end
```

I am putting together some logic that will iterate through each "profile" and write to my database (using Mysql gem)

```
testy_user[:search_templates].select { |p| p=[/^profile_/] }.each do |template|
  statement = @db.prepare('INSERT INTO profile (fk_user_id, default_search_form, name, default_profile, ref_required, fk_search_type_id) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)')
  statement.execute(@user_id, template[:default_search_form], template[:name], template[:default_profile], template[:ref_required], template[:fk_search_type_id])
end
```

As i am now in this loop each `template` is an array and i can no longer access the keys as symbols (I get TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer)

Do i need to convert each item of the array back into a hash or is there a cleaner way of approaching this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Your assumption of the problem you are facing is irrelevant to the actual problem.*

You `select` condition is wrong (*it is not even a condition, it is an assignment*). Moreover, you should explicitly define where is key (*i.e. `key`*) and where is corresponding to it element (*i.e. `_`* – underscore means, that you are not using it in the context of the block):

```
testy_user[:search_templates].select{|key, _| key =~ /^profile_/ }.each do |_, template|
  <your code>
end
```

Comment: apologies, typo meant i missed the curly braces with my `testy_user method`

Comment: Thank you for your help and clarifying my mistake